# Alamofire 4.0 / Swift 3.0 - Appending multipart form data (CSV file)

Tags: post, swift3, alamofire

I previously had a .post multiform upload working in Swift 2.2, which followed the following format (note that I'm not including all of the AlamoFire code...that would be too lengthy. I'm just including the relevant portions):

```
let data = mailStringArray[i].dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
csvDataArray.append(data!)

self.alamoFireManager.upload(.POST, "INSERT URL HERE", headers: header, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: csvDataArray[0], name: "bulk", fileName: "multi-input.csv", mimeType: "text/csv")
```

This worked perfectly. However, after migrating to Swift 3.0 and Alamofire 4.0, I'm now using the following format:

```
let data = String(mailStringArray[i]).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
            csvDataArray.append(data! as NSData)

 self.alamoFireManager.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in

multipartFormData.append(csvDataArray[0], withName: "bulk", fileName: "multi-input.csv", mimeType: "text/csv")

usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                             to:"INSERT URL HERE",
                             method:.post,
                             headers:["Authorization": "INSERT TOKEN HERE"],
                             encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
```

I end up getting the following error: **Cannot invoke argument append with an argument list of type '(NSData, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)'**

I'm thinking its because in Swift 3.0 i can no longer post NSData with a mimetype of "text/csv"....but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

multipartFormData.append(csvDataArray[0] **as Data**, withName: "bulk", fileName: "multi-input.csv", mimeType: "text/csv")